# Open standard for magazine?

Tags: epub, web-standards, rfc

Are there any standard for weekly digital magazines? That understand meta data of a magazine? Eg. issue number, date, author, editorial columns, series etc., so that content is searchable and presentable in a better intuitive GUI?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to clarify your question. The first part seems to refer to a file format for digital magazines, the second part to a file format for the metadata associated with a digital publication.

With respect to the metadata: there are several standards used in the industry. For examples:

- ONIX: http://www.editeur.org/8/ONIX/
- Dublin Core: http://dublincore.org/
- MARC: http://www.loc.gov/marc/

With respect to the file format for the publication itself, some formats that might be suitable for digital magazines:

- PDF
- EPUB (3) supports Fixed Layout, and the IDPF has a working group focussing on comics and digital magazine issues (Advanced/Hybrid Layout, or EPUB 3 AHL WG)
- Amazon Kindle has its own KF8 format
- HTML5 allows you to deliver pre-paginated contents by setting the viewport dimensions